# regex validation to accept percentage values

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am using regex to validate inputs  data by user data should be in percentage with decimal or without decimal, so I used regex but it is not working and in console not showing error I wonder if no error why this script is not working?

Expected output (allow only below format): number could be from 1-100

- 12.5% // any number between 1 -100
- 12%
- 12.45%

```js
$('#percentage').bind('keydown keypress keyup', on);

function on(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /^((100)|(\d{1,2}(\.\d*)?))%$/;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Percentage : <input type="text" id="percentage" />
```

Comment: You are using the regex on the wrong position. You are testing the key pressed to have a % attached every time. This won't work on user input.

Comment: On a side note, depending on how you want the validation/interaction to occur it's sometimes more straightforward to bind the `change` event on the field rather than key events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to validate input, you should listen to the `keyup` event and check the value of the input along with which key was pressed.

```js
const main = () => {
  $('#percentage').bind({
    focusin: onFocusIn,
    keyup: onChange
  });
};

const onFocusIn = (e) => {
  const $target = $(e.currentTarget);
  $target.data('val', $target.val());
};

const onChange = (e) => {
  const regex = /^((100)|(\d{1,2}(\.\d*)?))%?$/,
    $target = $(e.currentTarget),
    value = $target.val(),
    event = e || window.event,
    keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which,
    isValid = value.trim().length === 0 ||
      (keyInRange(keyCode) && regex.test(value));
  if (!isValid) {
    $target.val($target.data('val'));
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    $target.data('val', value);
  }
};

const keyInRange = (keyCode) =>
  (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57)     || /* top row numbers       */
  (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105)    || /* keypad numbers        */
  (keyCode === 110 || keyCode === 190) || /* decimal separator     */
  (keyCode === 53)                     || /* percentage            */
  (keyCode === 8 || keyCode === 46);      /* back-space and delete */

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="percentage">
  Percentage:
  <input type="text" id="percentage" placeholder="99.99%" />
</label>
```

Comment: thanks for your perfect answer, few things I am unable to get, so can't we use a single line regex to get this,because regex does everything with just single line of code

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking for simple to do value check set aside the events.
My gathering you need to check if value has % sign, secondly if value other than the % sign is number of decimal value. Now these are two conditions in their own right.

condition one check

```
if (!n.includes("%")||n.split('.').length > 2){return;}
```

It is short circuit replacement for regex to check if string contains what ever value you need to be present in it. if Its not simply return the function. On top of that it also makes a quick dash at checking string only contains single . character we dont want someone going 5.5.5.5.5%. if Its not simply return the function. 5% will work so will 5.5%.

Once % sign sexists then remove the % sign from value.

Once that is done simple check `Math.ceil(parseFloat(x))`all it does is takes the value rounds it up. If is returns number wala it worked I just created an alert you could do what ever you wanted from there on.

```js
function check(n){
if (!n.includes("%")||n.split('.').length > 2){return;}

x = n.replace("%", "");

if(Math.ceil(parseFloat(x))) {console.log(x); } 

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="percentage" onblur="check(this.value)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of the `#percentage` textbox, and not just the last pressed key.

So:
`if (!regex.test($('#percentage').value())) {`

or something along those lines